# What is the most elegant and efficient way to encoding strings to numeric values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, vectorization

One solution would be to use pandas.DataFrame.apply. But is there a more efficient way?+
In the following pattern is applied in the examples: AA = 0.0, AB = 0.5, BB = 1.0.

**Input Table**

| Index | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | AB | BB |
| Sample2 | AA | AB |

**Output Table**

| Index | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | 0.5 | 1.0 |
| Sample2 | 0.0 | 0.5 |

```
import pandas as pd
table_input = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ["AB", "BB"],
                          'Col2': ["AA", "AB"]},
                          index=['Sample1', 'Sample2'])
table_output = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [0.5, 1.0],
                          'Col2': [0.0, 0.5]},
                          index=['Sample1', 'Sample2'])
# Please insert solution here...
```

Comment: I guess [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) can be useful here.

Comment: It looks like you are using a key to map to numeric values. Perhaps map. Is there also a reason why apply is not sufficient?

Comment: do you define manually all `AA`/`AB`/`BB` (in which case use `table_output = table_input.replace({'AA': 0, 'AB': 0.5, 'BB': 1})`) or do you define `A` and `B` then consider `AB` the mean of `A` and `B`?

Comment: @JasonChia yes. I work with rather huge data. Apply would probably do the job just fine. But I'd like to use a faster way if possible.

Comment: @mozway the first option. There is no A or B. It is always AA, BB or AB.

Comment: @Pm740 OK (disappointed), then use `replace` (or `map` per column)…